# How to convert a minimal installation to a normal installation?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I'm just dowloading Ubuntu and enter the Linux world for the first time :)

In my installation I choose (minimal) instead of (normal), so I want to know what am I missing exactly?
And how can I restore/download the deleted packages?

If possible I want to get back everything in normal installation.

Comment: Judge for yourself: Install A, then install B, then compare. Many of us learned using that method. Some folks re-installed multiple times. Some folks still re-install different flavors and versions regularly.

Comment: How about 12 to 14 installs before I was happy.

Comment: Yeah, but can I know what is deleted from minimal version? Just to know, and then I choose what I want

Comment: See [this article](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-18-04-minimal-install-option) and [this article](https://www.fosslinux.com/3618/ubuntu-18-04-lts-minimal-installation-option-review.htm) on the difference between minimal and normal installation.

Comment: For me, when i installed minimal version 'accessibility' features were absent. Also i was not able to use touch-pad for 'pinch to zoom'. However these issues got solved when i installed full Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 2):

**What you are missing on an ubuntu-desktop-minimal install:**

- Open a terminal
- Run the command `apt install ubuntu-desktop --simulate`. It won't install anything.
- The resulting list are the packages (services and applications) that you chose to not install when you decided upon minimal.

**How to go from an ubuntu-desktop-minimal install to a full Ubuntu desktop:**

- Open a terminal
- Run the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. When prompted, enter your password (it WON'T echo on the screen. Enter it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. I always use minimal installation, and have no problem)
If you want some software you can always install it.